# Fedora 34 update was interupted and I cannot boot anymore, initamfs is not found

Tags: fedora, boot, grub2, uefi

I got a power cut during an update of my fedora 34 and now it does not boot anymore.

On the latest kernel I get the following message

```
error: ../../grub-core/fs/fshelp.c:257:file /initamfs-5.16.11-100.fc34.x86.64.img not found

Press any key to continue
```

On any of the other 2 kernels I reach the login screen but entering my password does not start the session, I am being prompted for my password again and again.

I have an encrypted disk (should that make any difference), I created a live media and I can uncrypt the disk so data is still there.

Is there any way for me to fix the install from the live media ?

Many thanks for helping me !!!!

Comment: Do you use any 3rd party kernel modules, such as the nvidia driver?

Comment: No, i use a thinkpad no nvidia in there. It seemed that I should be able to do something called a chroot but I can't find a proper tutorial